# Convert IPv6 address column from varchar(45) to varbinary(16) in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ip-address, ipv6

Does anyone know of a good script for converting `varchar(45)` to `varbinary(16)` in a T-SQL script?

In my table, the column using `varchar(16)` contains an IPv6 address as output by:

[IPAddress.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and I want it to contain the same value as output by:

[IPAddress.GetAddressBytes()](http://IPAddress.GetAddressBytes)

so that it can be stored in an `varbinary(16)` column.

Comment: What does this `varchar(45)` address look like?

Comment: There is a good example here for IPv4: http://forums.asp.net/t/1927965.aspx?Storing+IP+addresses+in+VARBINARY+16+from+asp+net+C+

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB have functions `INET6_ATON()`, etc.  This has SQL code to do the equivalent: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges